# C.find an error in a very small program.Calculating the sum of the first k numbers of the sequence

Tags: c, recursion, sequence

Calculating the sum of the first k numbers of the sequence  a[0] = 1, a[k] = k*a[k-1] +1/k ( k = 1, 2, ... ).

**UPD**

There is still a problem with the recursive function ...What is the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float m(float n){
    float k=1;
    float sum=k;
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<n;i++){
        k = (i*k+1.0/i);
        sum = sum+k;
    }
    return sum;
}

float Fn(float n)
{   
   if (n==0) {
   return 1;}
   
   return ((n*Fn(n-1)+1.0/n)+Fn(n-1));
  }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float k;
printf("input k : ");
scanf("%f",&k);
printf("res %f \n",Fn(k));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can do this with loops also.

Comment: Integer division: `1/n = 0`. Simply use `1.0/n`

Comment: @Damien what about then?shouldn't n be of type int?

Comment: `n` must be of type `int`, but `1/n` must be of type `float`

Comment: @Damien I fixed it to 1.0 but the program still doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand this part :`+ Fn(n-1)`... try to remove it

Comment: @I have to calculate the sum of the sequence

 still doesn't work

Comment: You have to decide if `Fn` is the nth element of the sequence, or the sum of the first n elements. You're using it as both.

Comment: @interjay Could you rewrite it for the sum correctly , please?

Comment: You need to use float variables to make a float sum.

Comment: Write a function that returns the nth element (not the sum) and use that to calculate the sum.

Comment: First things that jump out at me is that your return type is a float but your local vars are all ints.  You'll have implicit type conversion.  You're also returning an int instead of a float.  The compiler is likely to use different instructions based upon these types.  This can be easily spotted by setting /W4 or -Wall flags (depending on compiler) (High warning settings).

Your line `k = (n*k+1.0/n);` could do with brackets to make it clear what the sum function should be as well

Comment: @Steve all vars is float now , but sTiLl dOeSn't wOrK.. :(

Comment: sum = ++k; is odd as well, it means `k = k+1; sum = k;`  Is this what you intended?

Comment: @Steve I changed to `sum = sum+k;` , but problem still exist :(((

Comment: printf(), debugger....

Comment: `float m(int n){`
    `float k=1;`
    `float sum=k;`
    `float i;`
    `for (i=0; i < n; ++i ) //pre increment i as per sequence`
    `{`
        `k = (float)(( i * k ) + 1.0 / k ); //I believe this matches your sequence above.  Apologies about the casts`

        `sum += k;`
    `}`
    `return sum;`
`}`
`

Comment: Why are you reading the parameter from stdin instead of taking it from `argv`?

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues in your code:

- Integer division: 1/n = 0
- There was a confusion between the term value Fn and the sum value
- An iterative solution is simpler here than a recursive one

Here is a code, with both iterative and recursive implementations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float sum_fn(int n){
    float Fk = 1;
    float sum = Fk;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        Fk = i*Fk + 1.0/i;
        sum += Fk;
    }
    return sum;
}

float sum_recursive(int n, float *sum){
    if (n == 0) {
        *sum += 1.0;
        return 1.0;
    }
   float Fn = n * sum_recursive(n-1, sum) + 1.0/n;
   *sum += Fn;
   return Fn;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int k;
    printf("input k : ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("k = %d\tsum = %f\n", k, sum_fn(k));
    float sum = 0;
    sum_recursive(k, &sum);
    printf("k = %d\tsum = %f\n", k, sum);
    return 0;
}
```